# using positional occurence of value in the LHS of case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr

Can I use the positional occurrence of a value in the left-hand-side (LHS) of `dplyr::case_when()`?

In the example data, I would like to create `y` so that it only contains the last occurrence of `"A"` in `x` and the first occurrence of `"B"` in `x`.

#### Library and data:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Data
df <- tibble(
  x = c(NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, "B", "B"))
df
#> # A tibble: 7 x 1
#>   x    
#>   <chr>
#> 1 <NA> 
#> 2 A    
#> 3 A    
#> 4 <NA> 
#> 5 <NA> 
#> 6 B    
#> 7 B
```

#### Desired result

```r
tibble(
  x = c(NA, "A", "A", NA, NA, "B", "B"),
  y = c(NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "B", NA))
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 A     <NA> 
#> 3 A     A    
#> 4 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 6 B     B    
#> 7 B     <NA>
```

#### One of my failed attempts

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(
    y = case_when(
      x == last(x == "A")  ~ "A",
      x == first(x == "B") ~ "B")
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   x     y    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 2 A     <NA> 
#> 3 A     <NA> 
#> 4 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 <NA>  <NA> 
#> 6 B     <NA> 
#> 7 B     <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the position

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(y = replace(x, first(which(x  %in% "A")), NA),
           y = replace(y, last(which(x %in% "B")), NA))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  x     y    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 <NA>  <NA> 
#2 A     <NA> 
#3 A     A    
#4 <NA>  <NA> 
#5 <NA>  <NA> 
#6 B     B    
#7 B     <NA>
```

Or use `match` to get the index

```
df %>% 
   mutate(y = replace(x, c(match("A",  x), n() +1 - match("B", rev(x))), NA))
```

---

Or using `case_when`

```
df %>% 
  mutate(y = case_when((duplicated(x == "A", fromLast = TRUE) & 
           x %in% "A") |(duplicated(x == "B") & x %in% "B") ~ NA_character_,
          TRUE ~ x))
```

Comment: Thanks - So trying to use case_when() was a dead end it seems :-)

Comment: @SteenHarsted  Not really, here `replace` can take either numeric or logical index, while `case_when` needs a logical input.  One option is to convert it to logical with `row_number() == first(which(x %in% "A"))` in `case_when`